# XML Graphical Layout output does not match with Emulator output in android

Tags: android

In the layout view my xml looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xZ5f.png

But when I run my program, it looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzxmu.png

Why is this happening?

This is the layout file code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="50dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/quiztitle" />

</LinearLayout>  

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/quiz1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz1" />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/quiz2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/quiz3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz3" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation ="horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/quiz4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz4" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/quiz5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz5" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you to anyone that could help

Comment: is your emulator you designed have th same dimenssion as that of your device 
if no then confirm Dimension of both are same Like you might desiging in MDPi ad you are testing it in XHDP or HDPI then it will give the same result as you have shown in images 
According to Android the Best prectice is to desgin the layout of max Dimension like XHDPI and then use for it and lower than this as it works in hierarchical structure

Answer (score 1):

try this.. `android:gravity="center"` for main linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="50dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/quiztitle" />

</LinearLayout>  

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/quiz1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz1" />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/quiz2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/quiz3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz3" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation ="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/quiz4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz4" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/quiz5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/quiz5" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But didn't quite do what was the original xml layout. This was the output http://i.imgur.com/32yrAVJ.png

Comment: yeah gravity = center should work. I see you need to put proper margins as well.